# CakePHP: Easy way to populate select dropdown with grouped/nested choices?

Tags: forms, cakephp

Assuming I have Continents and Countries, and Continents hasMany Countries,
is there an easy way to create a select dropdown like this?

[image: $this->form->select('countries');]

I'm trying to write code like:

```
// in the controller
$this->set('countries', $this->Country->find('all', array('fields' ...)))

// in the view
$this->Form->select('countries')
```

I want to group these choices together, but avoid writing a lot of extra logic to re-arrange the data.

Answer (score 4):

If you form your array like this it will do it:

```
$countries = array(
    'North America' => array(
        123 => 'Canada'
        ...
        ...
    ),
    'South America' => array(
        345 => 'Argentina'
        ...
        ...
    ),
);
```

Then you use the form helper like normal.

```
$this->Form->select('countries');
```

#### Note

You can not use `find('all')` for selects. You need to use `find('list')` or reformat the data from `find('all')`